# Clear All Images From a Kivy Widget

Tags: python, kivy

In this code, `self.canvas.clear()` does erase a previously drawn board upon resize. However, it doesn't eliminate the images, and I found no method or variable in `Image()` that would help me do that. Instead, the images duplicate and hang in the background.

Here's the minimal example, all collapsed down from three different programs:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.image import AsyncImage
from kivy.config import Config
from kivy import graphics

def decodeFEN(from_path="FEN_now.txt"):
    this_FEN = "rnbqkbnr/pppppppp/8/8/8/8/PPPPPPPP/RNBQKBNR w KQkq - 0 1".split(" ")
    piece_placement = this_FEN[0]
    for x in range(1, 9):
        piece_placement = piece_placement.replace(str(x), "1" * x)
    piece_placement = [list(a) for a in piece_placement.split("/")]
    this_FEN[0] = piece_placement
    print(this_FEN)
    return this_FEN

def encodeFEN(): #TODO: Create a program that renders a board state to an FEN.
    pass

class GameState():
    def __init__(self):
        self.fen_state = decodeFEN()
        self.board = list(sorted([c for d in
                      [[(a, (7 - b), self.fen_state[0][b][a], chr(a+97)+str(8-b)) for b in range(0,8)] for a in range(0,8)]
                      for c in d], key=lambda i: (i[1], i[0])))

# Define the pieces as a dictionary of the FEN keys to image values.
def loadImages():
    images = {}
    for p in ["b", "k", "n", "q", "p", "r",
              "B", "K", "N", "Q", "P", "R"]:
        if p == p.lower():
            color_tag = "b"
        else:
            color_tag = "w"
        # Populate this dictionary with the relevant image paths.
        # images[p] = "Images/{0}{1}.png".format(color_tag, p.upper())
        images[p] = "https://kivy.org/logos/kivy-logo-black-64.png"
    return images

image_dic = loadImages()
game_state = GameState()

class Chessboard(Widget):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Chessboard, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.bind(pos=self.drawBoardandPieces)
        self.bind(size=self.drawBoardandPieces)
        self.drawBoardandPieces()

    def drawBoardandPieces(self, *args):
        with self.canvas:
            # Reset everything in case of redraws.
            self.canvas.clear()
            for img in self.ids:
                img.piece_img.source = ""
                img.piece_img.reload()
            # Define the lengths of the edges of the squares.
            edge_len = min(self.height, self.width) // 8
            Config.set("graphics", "resizable", True)
            for column in range(0, 8):
                for row in range(0, 8):
                    if ((row + column) % 2) == 0:
                        graphics.Color(0, 0, 1)
                        self.dark_rect = graphics.Rectangle(pos=(column*edge_len, row*edge_len), size=(edge_len, edge_len))
                    else:
                        graphics.Color(1, 1, 1)
                        self.light_rect = graphics.Rectangle(pos=(column*edge_len, row*edge_len), size=(edge_len, edge_len))
                    piece_in_pos = [a[2] for a in game_state.board if (a[0] == column) and (a[1] == row)][0]
                    if piece_in_pos != "1":
                        # self.piece_img = Image(source=image_dic[piece_in_pos])
                        self.piece_img = AsyncImage(source=image_dic[piece_in_pos])
                        self.piece_img.allow_stretch = True
                        self.piece_img.keep_ratio = True
                        self.piece_img.opacity = 1
                        self.piece_img.pos = (column*edge_len, row*edge_len)
                        self.piece_img.size = (edge_len, edge_len)
                        self.add_widget(self.piece_img)

class SCApp(App):
    def build(self):
        app_layout = BoxLayout(orientation="horizontal")
        app_layout.add_widget(widget=Chessboard())
        return app_layout

SCApp().run()
```

Comment: You shouldn't be creating widgets within the `with canvas` block, this probably results in them being drawn twice. However, that doesn't explain your results.

Comment: Also, post a minimal _runnable_ example.

Comment: @inclement, I loaded the necessary code to make the widget runnable.

Comment: Please post a minimal runnable example - that is, cut out as much as you can while still having it work. A single code block that can be copied and pasted is ideal.

Comment: @inclement, done and done.

Comment: You were right. Moving the loop to add the widgets out of the `with_canvas` block solved the problem. It turns out that the first drawing of the pieces apears behind the tiles every time, but they aren't deleted when `self.clear_widgets()` is called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to notes from @inclement and @john-anderson, I solved the issue. It turns out that (drawings of[?]) the images appear behind the drawn board, as well, but can't be deleted with `self.clear_widgets()`:

```
def drawBoardandPieces(self, *args):
    with self.canvas:
        # Reset everything in case of redraws.
        self.canvas.clear()
        # Define the lengths of the edges of the squares.
        edge_len = min(self.height, self.width) // 8
        Config.set("graphics", "resizable", True)
        for column in range(0, 8):
            for row in range(0, 8):
                if ((row + column) % 2) == 0:
                    graphics.Color(0, 0, 1)
                    self.dark_rect = graphics.Rectangle(pos=(column*edge_len, row*edge_len), size=(edge_len, edge_len))
                else:
                    graphics.Color(1, 1, 1)
                    self.light_rect = graphics.Rectangle(pos=(column*edge_len, row*edge_len), size=(edge_len, edge_len))
    self.clear_widgets()
    for column in range(0, 8):
        for row in range(0, 8):
            piece_in_pos = [a[2] for a in game_state.board if (a[0] == column) and (a[1] == row)][0]
            if piece_in_pos != "1":
                self.piece_img = Image(source=image_dic[piece_in_pos])
                self.piece_img.allow_stretch = True
                self.piece_img.keep_ratio = True
                self.piece_img.opacity = 1
                self.piece_img.pos = (column*edge_len, row*edge_len)
                self.piece_img.size = (edge_len, edge_len)
                self.add_widget(self.piece_img)
```

Comment: I think the problem is that the widgets were added to the canvas twice, but the clear only removed them once.

Answer (score 0):

The `canvas.clear()` method only clears canvas instructions, things like `Color`, `Rectangle`, etc. It does not affect the list of child widgets (those added using `add_widget()`). If you are completely redrawing your chess board, then you should probably clear the child widgets as well as clearing the canvas. Try adding:

```
self.clear_widgets()
```

along with your `canvas.clear()`.

Comment: I tried this, too, but to no avail. The images appear in the background.

Comment: I also updated the code to make it runnable, if you'd be willing to give it another look.